# Htaccess redirection to add string in all url with matching format

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Pl advise

**Incorrect URL**

```
     www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_usedtoy&view=category&limitstart=495
     www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_usedtoy&view=category&limitstart=510
     www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_usedtoy&view=category&limitstart=525
```

**Correct URL**

```
     www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_usedtoy&view=category&Itemid=2&limitstart=495
     www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_usedtoy&view=category&Itemid=2&limitstart=510
     www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_usedtoy&view=category&Itemid=2&limitstart=525
```

How to add Itemid=2 in all url which match incorrect url format of usedtoy - which has Itemid missing

Edit
**After using the htaccess code**

New result is

```
     www.abc.com/index.php?Itemid=2&option=com_usedtoy&view=category&limitstart=90
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)option=com_usedtoy(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)Itemid=2(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %{REQUEST_URI}/%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(index\.php)/(option=com_usedtoy&view=category)&((?!Itemid=2&).+)$ /$1?$2&Itemid=2&$3 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava - but there's no change. It does not add in Itemid=2 - after making changes in htaccess !!! Also - is it a 301 redirect. Pl guide. thanks

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, but its giving a wrong result. Am highlighting in edit

Comment: Reason - search engines will treat it as duplicate pages. Hence - its required to be present in order. thanks

Comment: wokrs perfectly now. Thanks once again for your time, expertise and knowledge sharing on the topic

Comment: Hi Anubhava - need your help on this query in htaccess- can you advise pl thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766391/moving-site-from-http-to-https-what-changes-needed-in-htaccess/50771536#50771536