# Moving site from http to https. What changes needed in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, https

Am changing site from http to https
Have this code in htaccess

Can any one advise - should i just change from http to https whereever mentioned
Thanks

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+http://.+?(/index\.php\?[^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /index\.php\%(25)*3[Ff]([^\ ]*)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]

##### File injection protection -- BEGIN
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=http:// [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=(\.\.//?)+ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=/([a-z0-9_.]//?)+ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
##### File injection protection -- END

########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section
```

Comment: Are you using apache or Windows  server?

Comment: apache server is using

Comment: dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489895/http-to-https-through-htaccess

Comment: @Ruchika: Did you try answer suggested by starkeen ?

Comment: i think starkeen answer is different as i already know how to redirect from http to https at domain level. But have some redirects already in htaccess - unsure should i change from http to https now